# Random method return two values without duplicate

Tags: c#

I created two methods that take random values from database table

This method will return an integer random value

```
private int GetDayValue()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    List<int> days = GetDays();
    int r = rnd.Next(days.Count);
    return days[r];
}
```

This method will return also an integer random value

```
private int GetPeriodValue(string grd_id)
{ 
    Random rnd = new Random();
    List<int> periods = GetPeriods(grd_id);
    int r = rnd.Next(periods.Count);
    return periods[r];
}
```

Here there is a `for` loop will take random value from two methods

```
for (int z = 0; z <= secPortion; z++)
{
    //here the random value of day
    day = GetDayValue();

    //here the random value of period
    period = GetPeriodValue(grd_id);   

    //this method will insert the value on database table                  
    SetFirstShot(teacher, sub, sec, period, day);                             
}
```

My question:

I want to create method will return random value of day and period together for example random value (ex: `3,5 ... 4,6 .... 1,1`) and not repeated during the loop for example `4,6` will generated once time then another random value but if it `4,6` the method will create again a random value.

Comment: So you'll have to check the database table each time a random is generated to see if it exists. Instead you could generate a list or array of randomly generated day/period combinations and check to see if the value is in the list/array, then insert into your database all at once. I don't think there is any magic bullet here though.

Comment: Are you simply looking for a guaranteed unique value, and it does not have to be a number? If so, you can use C#'s Guid.NewGuid().

Comment: Not sure if this was a typo, but are you wanting `4,6` to return the _same_ value again or a _different_ value each time regardless of inputs? If it's the latter, definitely use `Guid.NewGuid()`.

Comment: You have less than a hundred items here. Simply push them all into a list then run a fisher-yates shuffle on the list.

Comment: You'll want to move that instantiation of `Random` out of the method. Otherwise it'll keep giving you the same combination more often than you'd like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to use KeyValuePair and I solved, its works well !
Here the code that I used:

```
    // I created a list contain two pairs..
        List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> dictionary = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
        for (int z = 0; z < secPortion; z++)
        {
        day = GetDayValue();
        period = GetPeriodValue(grd_id);

    //here I pass the value of day and period to the pairs
        KeyValuePair<int, int> myItem = new KeyValuePair<int, int>(day, period);
//here I created a list which is the list of values for the random key, if it is exist or not.
        List<int> values = (from kvp in dictionary where kvp.Key == day select kvp.Value).ToList();

    // this is a bool variable its value by default is true, once there is a duplicated value it will be changed to false....

    bool FirstChecker = true;
        if (values.Contains(period))
        {
        FirstChecker = false;
        z--;
        }
        else
        {
        dictionary.Add(myItem);
        SetFirstShot(teacher, sub, sec, period, day);
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hash function instead that has a good random distribution aspect to it. A hash function with return the same value for the same inputs each time, while the results will "seem" random, which might be all the "randomness" you need.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

// ...

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
using (var hash = MD5.Create())
{
    writer.Write(day);
    writer.Write(period);
    var data = md5Hash.ComputeHash(stream.ToArray());
    var randomNumber = BitConverter.ToInt32(data);
}
```

The added benefit is that you don't have to store previously-computed values in any sort of database. Any two agents with the same hashing algorithm will generate the same hashes. The values may not be completely unique, but they should vary wildly from input to input while also being *deterministic* with no hidden state. Truly unique would require querying outside state and probably introduce race conditions if your system is distributed.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `GetDays()` and `GetPersiodValue()` returns two `int` lists, so I'm writing two mock methods for those.

```
static List<int> GetDays()
{
    return new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
}

static List<int> GetPeriods()
{
    return new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
}
```

First thing you need to do is move the `new Random()` out of the methods (so that it's outside the loop). Otherwise when you iterate so fast it will keep giving you the same number.

```
static int GetRandomDay(Random rnd)
{
    var days = GetDays();
    return days[rnd.Next(days.Count)];
}

static int GetRandomPeriod(Random rnd)
{
    var periods = GetPeriods();
    return periods[rnd.Next(periods.Count)];
}
```

Then I'll do something like this to see if the generated pair of random values were generated before. Add to a list (or DB in your case) if not.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var RandomList = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();

    Random rnd = new Random();

    for (int i =0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        bool isUnique = false;
        do
        {
            int day = GetRandomDay(rnd);
            int period = GetRandomPeriod(rnd);
            if(RandomList.Where(x => x.Item1 == day && x.Item2 == period).FirstOrDefault() == null)
            {
                RandomList.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(day, period));
                isUnique = true;
            }

        } while (!isUnique);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx#UniqueArray) is what you need.

> Although the example is a solution for a one-dimensional array, actually in your case the two list `days` and `periods` can be mapped to one sequence whose length is `days.Count * periods.Count`. Or you can do this for each list separately but some cases will be missed.